# How to use Lodash to create nested divs

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, lodash

With the following code:

```
_.chunk(_.range(4), 2)
```

I get these nested arrays:

```
[[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

How could I use the Lodash method `_.chunk()` to create something like this:

```
<div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: you'll need to use `.map` after `_.chunk` to create that output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this for example

```
    const arr = _.chunk(_.range(4), 2);
    return (
      <div>
        {arr.map(sub =>
          <div>
            {sub.map(elem =>
              <div>{elem + 1}</div>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
```